# Toolbar & Back button issue in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

i am creating a toolbar application, in that application all toolbar icons and actions done successfully.But when i used the icon for next view calling and from that view i am calling a back button  then it will crashed..here i am adding my code

/////In View Did load

```
    objectLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
   objectLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);
   objectLabel.text = @"Press Button";
   [self.view addSubview:objectLabel];
   NSLog(@"label");
   objectToolbar=[UIToolbar new];
    objectToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
   [objectToolbar sizeToFit];
   objectToolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 410, 320, 50);
   NSLog(@"toolbar");

   UIBarButtonItem *systemItem1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton1:)];

   UIBarButtonItem *systemItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton2:)];

   UIBarButtonItem *systemItem3 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(pressButton3:)];
   UIBarButtonItem *flexItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                          target:nil
                                                                          action:nil];
   NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: systemItem1, flexItem, systemItem2, flexItem, systemItem3, nil];
   [objectToolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
   [self.view addSubview:objectToolbar];
```

///after that

```
 -(void) pressButton1:(id)sender{
   // objectLabel.text = @"Add";
       FirstViewController *objectFirstViewController=[[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
       [self.view addSubview:objectFirstViewController.view];

   }

 -(void) pressButton2:(id)sender{
objectLabel.text = @"Take Action";
 }  

-(void) pressButton3:(id)sender{
objectLabel.text = @"Camera";
}
```

///in FirstViewController.m

```
   -(IBAction)back:(id)sender
    {
      ViewController *objectViewController=[[ViewController  alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
      [self.view addSubview:objectViewController.view];
   }
```

When i clicked the back  button  it will crashed..please give me the solution

Comment: Please post the crash message. Is there anything in your viewWillAppear method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just remove from superview of the current view for ex..

```
   [self.view removeFromSuperview]; 

 // or  if you want to call the method from your MainViewController use this line [objectFirstViewController removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: `[objectFirstViewController removeFromSuperview];` will not work since he is calling from the second class.

Comment: yes dude but if he is want to call the button from first class then it is useful right dude??

Comment: [self.view removeFromSuperview];

Comment: see first create one method in your  mainclass and also create object globaly like this in .h file FirstViewController *objectFirstViewController; and in this method remove like this.. -(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{

  [objectFirstViewController removeFromSuperview];
} try this and just comment if any query faced dude..

Answer (score 2):

In order to go back you shouldn't be creating a new object of previous class and add it again. Instead you need to remove the current subview from superview to go back.

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{

  [self.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

It is better to use navigation or model transition for this instead of just doing an `addSubView`.

Comment: thanks@ACB &@Paras ..  used navigation instead of addsubview..solved my issue..Thanks very much..:-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing `[self.view addSubview:Viewcontroller.view];` it follows logically that you should do `[self.view removeFromSuperview];` in the added subview. Nonetheless, it is advisable that you use a navigation controller and do push/pop operations to show/remove views. If your problem is the navigation bar, you could hide it via `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;` and use your toolbar as a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

instead of this;

```
[self.view addSubview:objectFirstViewController.view];
```

use

[self.navigationController pushViewController:objectFirstViewController animated:YES];

and at Viewdidload of FirstviewController set,

self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=YES;

and use this

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Thats it.